# Regular expression to capture 3 strings in quotation marks separated by space

Tags: javascript

ok, I guess the code says it all.

```
//I have this string.
var str = '"Watch out" "for the" "rock!"'
//this is one of the many patterns that I tried
res=str.match(/"(.*)" "(.*)" "(.*)"/g)
```

I want an array like: `res=["Watch out","for the","rock!"]`
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var str = '"Watch out" "for the" "rock!"'
res=str.match(/"(.*?)" "(.*?)" "(.*?)"/)
res.shift()
```

You need to remove the `g` flag because with that flag you will get a list of matches and not the list of groups for a single match. Also, you should specify your groups as non-greedy (quantifier `*?`), otherwise they might match too much. Finally, remove the first entry from the array using `res.shift()` - the first entry is the entire matched string and you want only the groups.

Comment: well that's interesting. Didn't know about the second meaning of '?'. Thank you.

Comment: if I don't shift the result, the whole string will be repeated as the first element of the array. why?

Comment: @AlexStack: The first entry of the array is always "group zero" - meaning the part of the string corresponding to the entire match. In your case all of `str` matched but it doesn't have to be like that, e.g. if `str` is `hey "Watch out" "for the" "rock!" there`. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

`/"[^"]*"\s?/g` should be a better regex for splitting up any amount of values separated by quotations and spaces.

Comment: this one is good but it gives me ['"Watch out"' ,'"for the"' ,'"rock!"']. I need it without quotations.

Answer (score 1):

```
res = str.match(/^"([^"]*)" "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"$/).slice(1)
```

Comment: this one works, but why slice(1)? I removed it and the whole string was placed as res[0]. I don't understand why?

Comment: @AlexStack the very first entry in the `match` result is always the whole string. `slice(1)` gives the array without this first element.

Answer (score 1):

About regular expression I can suggest you the following web site: [RegEx LIB](http://regexlib.com/%28A%285EUS2AMJhBbzC9zcYLNAb_BDWJtNCEAYZiSsa71XpUY8ohNtNQ9ZO_aLYADFszFw4lvjABHJGRLt-blDOMeveNgMDHQOQnWoM-aJ41E1lUi3H-pZW2biJ-yJ-cR8_ma61PzqDDeFXM0YDatrphDQAtNrBCxjh6C-th0vGweCC3dYzO7kdXJ5gK9gzBjQPOGh0%29%29/Search.aspx?k=&c=4&m=-1&ps=20). It contains many regular expressions (the link I sent you is directly for String category). 
Moreover you can test your regular expressions (also using Client Side engine - Javascript) at [REG Tester](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx).

I am sure there you can find your wished regular expression and you can also refer to it everytime you will need a regulare expression.

I use it every time I need RegEX in my projects.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. As a proverb say: "if you want to feed someone for a day, give him a fish, if you want to feed them for a lifetime, teach them fishing" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [Ktash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316391/regular-expression-to-capture-3-strings-in-quotation-marks-separated-by-space/7316432#7316432), but using a capture group (the brackets) to get only the text within the quotation marks:

/"([^"]*)"\s?/g;

The only problem is that `match()` doesn't return capture groups with a global modifier. So have to use in `split()` or `RegExp.exec()` which gets more messy:

**Option 1 - Using RegExp.exec()**

```
str = '"Watch out" "for the" "rock!"'
re = /"([^"]*)"\s?/g;
result = [];
match = re.exec(str);
while (match != null) {
     result.push(match[1]);
     match = re.exec(str);
}
```

Each call to `re.exec(str)` returns the captured group until none are remaining when it will return `null`. If you called it again, it would start again, i.e:

```
> str = '"Watch out" "for the" "rock!"'
  ""Watch out" "for the" "rock!""
> re = /"([^"]*)"\s?/g;
  /"([^"]*)"\s?/g;
> re.exec(str)
  [""Watch out" ", "Watch out"]
> re.exec(str)
  [""for the" ", "for the"]
> re.exec(str)
  [""rock!"", "rock!"]
> re.exec(str)
  null
> re.exec(str)
  [""Watch out" ", "Watch out"]
```

As per all the other answers here, the results returned are an array containing the whole match and then the capture group, hence why `match[1]` is used.

**Option 2 - Using split()**

```
str = '"Watch out" "for the" "rock!"'
re = /"([^"]*)"\s?/; //The global identifier isn't needed
result = str.split(re)
result = result.filter(function(e){if (e!==""){return true}}) //Remove blanks from array
```

`.split()` accepts a regex, however the results of `str.split(re)` are:

> ["", "Watch out", "", "for the", "", "rock!", ""]

so it is necessary to use the `filter()` function to remove the blank entries. I think the `split()` approach is more elegant, but I think Internet Explorer (at least up to 8) lacks the `filter()` function.